# Heritrix retrieves gzip CSS + JS

Tags: java, javascript, css, heritrix

When I run Heritrix my web-server gzip's JS + CSS assets.

This is turning out to be a problem because when loading the .warc file through Wayback, it's still encoded as gzip.

I am unable to view the .css + .js files properly in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your question is:

> When I run Heritrix my web-server gzip's JS + CSS assets.

Heritrix creates a warc and gzips it.

> This is turning out to be a problem because when loading the .warc file through Wayback, it's still encoded as gzip.

It is compressed. Hence you can decompress it.

> I am unable to view the .css + .js files properly in the browser.

Wayback Machine renders a web page from a warc file. It is not a file viewer.

If you want to have a look at the CSS files, decompress the archive with gunzip, open the warc file with an editor and search for it.